# Find the Rotation Count in Rotated Sorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, rotation

I got the following question:
Consider an array of distinct numbers sorted in increasing order. The array has been rotated (clockwise) k number of times. Given such an array, find the value of k.

I understand it's a well-known question which has been asked (and that there are some answers in the web for that), but my question is not about the solution to this problem.

I had this problem in a test, and I said that a solution to this problem can be:  to find the first number that is smaller than the predecessors in the array. The way I chose to do it is to do increasing jumps with the power of 2 from the start of the array. I will demonstrate:
assume k=29
then I will check 2,4,8,16,32. the value in place 32 is smaller but not the first. then I will jump from place 17 (jumping described above): 17, 19, 23, 31. place 31 is smaller and but not the first.
next stage check: 24,26,30. this time the value in place 30 is smaller and first so return 30-1.
(I can write this as algorithm, but I think that the demonstrate clear the thinking)

My thinking is that this will work recursively and will certainly give me the answer. 
My lecturer said to me that I was wrong.
So my question is do I really wrong?
secondly, I struggled to find the running time of the algorithm. I know the first run is a most O(logk) and the other runs (on the sub-arrays) are less, but what is the sum of then in the worst case. I tell you the truth I thought at first it will still be o(logk), but now I don't really sure about it.

thank you.

Comment: If you jump in powers of 2 there is no guarantee you will ever find the k value. I dont think you can get better than O(n)

Comment: Your algorithm is similar to an [exponential search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search). And your algorithm will work. It's just not the most efficient way to solve the problem. The most efficient way is a simple [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Comment: @user3386109 can you evaluate the running time of my algorithm?

Comment: Worst case `k` is approximately `n`, i.e. the position that you're looking for is near the end of the array. In that case, the running time of the algorithm is `log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + ...` If we say that `x = log(n)` then the sum is `x + x-1 + x-2 + ... + 1` which is `x(x+1)/2` which is O(x^2). So I would say that the time complexity of your algorithm is O(log(n) * log(n))

Comment: Why did you stoped at 30 in your example? How the steps will be different if `k=27`?